# Can relativistic mass be used in place of total energy?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, mass-energy

I was doing some practice questions regarding relativistic kinematics and I just had a question, We write total energy of an object as;
$$ E^{2} = m_{0}^{2}c^{4} + p^{2}c^{2}$$

Where $m_{0}$ is the rest mass. Now if we replace $m_{0}$ with it's relativistic alternative;

$$m = \gamma m_0$$ Where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.

Can I remove the kinetic energy term $(p^{2}c^{2})$, since the kinetic energy is now counted as the mass increase or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was doing some practice questions regarding relativistic kinematics and I just had a question, We write total energy of an object as;
> $$ E^{2} = m_{0}^{2}c^{4} + p^{2}c^{2}$$
>
> Where $m_{0}$ is the rest mass. Now if we replace $m_{0}$ with it's relativistic alternative;
>
> $$m = \gamma m_0$$ Where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.
>
> Can I remove the kinetic energy term $(p^{2}c^{2})$...

Yes, you can write:
$$
E = \gamma m_0 c^2\;,
$$
which can be squared to see that:
$$
E^2 = \gamma^2 m_0^2 c^4\;.
$$

---

As a notational aside, I would personally advise against using the notation $m$ for relativistic mass, since many many people prefer to use $m$ for rest mass. I.e., just use $m$ for rest mass and use $\gamma m$ for relativistic mass.

Comment: One problem with $\gamma m$ notation is that it doesn't work if the rest mass is zero. And, of course, using it indicates no respect for the history of $E=mc^2$, its cultural significance, and its profound implications.

Comment: This is the Physics Stack Exchange, not the Hypothetical Cultural Significance Stack Exchange....

Comment: How is your preference for $\gamma m$ anything beyond a cultural statement?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to die on this hill?

Comment: Who's dying? Not me. But physics itself is in a bit of trouble, losing sight of the fundamental phenomena. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIhk9eKOLzQ